# Removing a single pointer from a boost::ptr_list list?

Tags: boost, list, containers

If I create a bunch of elements in a boost::ptr_list container how can I remove individual pointers from it? Say I do this:

boost::ptr_list intlist;
int *i = new int(3);
intlist.Add(i);
int *i2 = new int(1);
intlist.Add(i2);
int *i3 = new int(6);
intlist.Add(i3);

How can I remove say i3 and not i or i2 from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `pop_back()` command](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/pop_back/) deletes the last element of a list. Boost's implementation of `ptr_list` encapsulates a `std::list`, so all of the commands on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) are equally valid with Boost's pointer wrappers.

Since you changed your question, see [the erase command](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/). You won't find an answer except by using the std::list interface.

Comment: Note that `ptr_list` has `transfer` instead of `splice`, and the order of the arguments is not the same.